# SQL Query must return rows from ProductMaster and 2 other tables

Tags: sql

I've got 3 tables:

1. ProductMaster
2. SalesTY (Sales This Year)
3. SalesLY (Sales Last Year)

I'm trying to create a query which will return all the rows from the ProductMaster and then the sales from this year and then the sales from last year.  The problem is some products from this year is new and some products from last year is not available anymore, but I've got to list all the prodcuts, so it must look like this:

```
Product    TY       LY
aaaa       1000     0
bbbb       0        1000
```

My query:

```
select 
i.Product
,b1.TrnMonth
,b1.TrnYear
,b1.TY
,b2.LY
from Productmaster i
left join #ty b1
on i.Product = b1.Product
left join #ly b2
on i.Product = b2.Product
Group by i.Product
,b1.TrnMonth
,b1.TrnYear
```

Comment: What is the output right now? Seems like it should give results.

Comment: You need to edit your question to more clearly state what your problem is. Show a sample of the results you are getting, and show more precisely the the results you want. And/or better describe the layout of the tables.

Comment: What is b1(TY).TrnMonth and TrnYear supposed to do here? Its not in your output example so its very unclear how you intend it to be used.  Worse, how is it supposed to relate to b2(LY) in your GROUP BY/rollups?

Answer (score 0):

you need `LEFT OUTER JOIN` i think.

Comment: Not quite, you'll get cross-multiplication from the TY and LY tables.

Answer (score 0):

Its unclear how your `GROUP BY` and the `TY.TrnYear` and `TrnMonth` columns are supposed to relate to the LY table in you results.

Excluding them and just going on your output example (which also excludes them), I would use this query:

```
SELECT
    i.Product
    , COALESCE((Select SUM(TY) From #ty b1 Where i.Product = b1.Product), 0) As TY
    , COALESCE((Select SUM(LY) From #ly b2 Where i.Product = b2.Product), 0) As LY    
FROM Productmaster i
```

You should not be joining TY and LY to each other without special conditioning as they will cross-multiply the results rows.